# What are the formula of representation of quasicrystals and the law or mechanism of the formation

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, computability-theory, physics, statistical-physics, tiling

I vaguely recall that  formula  of  representation of quasicrystals is relevant to tiling plane,and  tiling plane without period  is relevant to recursiveness, and do not know the mechanism or physics law by which the quasicrystals are produced or formed.

What are the formula  of  representation of quasicrystals and the law or mechanism of the formation

Comment: Why to downvote the post?Hao Wang had a book on mathematical logic part of which is about tiling plane and recursion. But he has not made any connection between quasi-crystals and tiling.I vaguely recall that some famous physicist (C.N. Yang?) has comment on such a connection.

Comment: I didn't vote this down, but I think you can do more research before asking and this would help you to make a question that is more informative and easier to answer. There are different definitions of quasicrystal, and many ways to produce them such as slicing a higher dimensional lattice, and there doesn't have to be any connection with a physical law. Have you read the Wikipedia entry on quasicrystals?

Comment: @DouglasZare,thank you for your comment.Yes I have to do more research in advance.You know,I have some physics knowledge,so sometimes it is somehow easy for me to understand a question in term of physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look at work of Charles Radin: [listed here](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/radin/tiling.html), especially the survey article #8 and the book review #11.